# Need an http proxy that can set custom cache keys

Tags: caching, redirect, squid, http-proxy

I need to set up an http proxy that can set a custom cache key for returned content. It seems that squid2.7 may have been able to do this using the storeurl_rewrite_program feature, however this feature is not yet ported to squid3. Is there some other way to do this, either using squid or some other http proxy software? If that software also can cooperate with external servers for access control to cache objects that's a bonus but it's not immediately necessary.

The use case is that I want to cache frequently used data for quick access from otherwise slow storage. This storage is accessed by http to a frontend which always returns a 302 (temporary move) redirect to one of the redundant disk servers that actually hold the data. The data files that I want to cache are public, static and typically a few gigabytes in size, and are thus ideal for caching. However, the redirect urls will contain authentication tokens and will therefore always be unique, effectively negating the cache. On the other hand, it is trivial to reconstruct the original urls from the redirect urls, so if the proxy server can do that and use those for cache keys, well then the cache is back in business.

Getting the storeurl_rewrite_program feature into squid3 is flagged as important here:

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/RoadMap/Squid3

but it is highly uncertain whether it will make it into squid3.3 or even squid3.4, and squid2.7 is scheduled for obsoletion by the release of squid3.2.

About access control, it seems that squid should be able to do that using the external_acl_type feature, but providing cached access to protected data is not terribly important at this stage, so for now I consider that to be just sugar on the top.